# How to remove a selected part of an image in Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, image-processing

I want to send an image to backend, but before sending user can select some part of it. And I need to remove unwanted part. Below I attached some screenshots.[image: the first image]

[image: the second]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After three days of working on it I finally found out, how to work around.
So if it's not an eraser I'm just drawing as always but if an eraser I'm replacing Paint with shader wich is my image from background.

```
 if (!_eraser) {
    paint = new Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..color = selectedColor
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
  } else {
    final Float64List deviceTransform = new Float64List(16)
      ..[0] = devicePixelRatio
      ..[5] = devicePixelRatio
      ..[10] = 1.0
      ..[15] = 2.0;
    paint = new Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..shader = ImageShader(image, TileMode.repeated, TileMode.repeated, deviceTransform)
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
```

Painting Class

```
@override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, new Paint());

    for (int i = 0; i < pointsList.length - 1; i++) {
      if (pointsList[i] != null && pointsList[i + 1] != null) {
        canvas.drawLine(pointsList[i].points, pointsList[i + 1].points, pointsList[i].paint);

      } else if (pointsList[i] != null && pointsList[i + 1] == null) {
        offsetPoints.clear();
         offsetPoints.add(pointsList[i].points);
         offsetPoints.add(Offset(pointsList[i].points.dx + 0.1, pointsList[i].points.dy + 0.1));
         canvas.drawCircle(pointsList[i].points, pointsList[i].paint.strokeWidth / 2, pointsList[i].paint);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: can you post an image or gif of how it works?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to crop the image basic on some user input that you already have, you could use the `copyCrop` function from the [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image) library.

Comment: I don't want to crop, I want to remove unwanted part and keep the size, like eraser

Comment: You want to achieve exactly what you've done in the screenshots? If not could you please add a screenshot of the final image you want (the one with the removed part)?

Comment: hey man sorry for late answer that things I didn't do yet but I'm working on it